# Получить фон экрана в виде bitmap

Tags: android

Хочу сделать блюр заднего фона окошка отрытого поверх всех окон, но не могу понять как нарисовать в битмапу весь экран (не view) чтобы заблюрить его и отрисовать в виде фона

```
public class NotificationView extends View {
    private Context context;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private Drawable icon;
    private boolean isDrawningNow = false;
    public NotificationView(Context context, String title, String content, Drawable icon) {
        super(context);
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (isDrawningNow) {
            return;
        }
        isDrawningNow = true;
        Bitmap screen = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas screenCanvas = new Canvas(screen);
        getRootView().draw(screenCanvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(blur(screen), 0, 0, null);
        isDrawningNow = false;
    }

    public static Bitmap blur(Bitmap image) {
      //...
    }
}

public void newNotification(String title, String content, String image, int duration) {
        notificationView = new NotificationView(this, title, content, null, duration);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams (
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.addView(notificationView, params);

}
```

При загрузке битмапа в галерею:

```
            WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams (
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );

    params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    final TextView t = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    t.setText("test");
    t.setTextSize(30);
    windowManager.addView(t, params);

    create.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            View rv = t.getRootView();
            Bitmap screen = Bitmap.createBitmap(rv.getWidth(), rv.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(screen);
            rv.draw(c);
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), screen ,"nameofimage" , "description");
        }
    });
```

[image: что сохраняется]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятна суть вопроса. Но возможно [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641973/how-to-blur-background-images-in-android) поможет. А вообще, если вам нужна просто размытая фоновая картинка, то ее проще сделать графическом редакторе.

Comment: У вас есть попытка решения? Если да, добавте ваш код прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не могу получить битмапу с изображением экрана, включая статус бар и т.п

Comment: @АлексейБахметьев, судя по коду вы его все же получаете, просто ничего с ним дальше не делаете.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить скриншот экрана в виде **Bitmap**, подойдет этот код.

```
public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Но судя по вашему коду вы его и так уже получаете, просто не видите этого, потому что дальше никак не используете полученный Bitmap.

Comment: Я пробовал сохранить полученный Bitmap в галерею и там где я хочу видеть фон у меня просто чёрный экран. Мне нужно получить картинку того, что находится под View, который добавляется ПОВЕРХ всех окон